# Identical values generated from random samples from a uniform distribution in dplyr

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse, uniform-distribution

This is a follow up to previous question. My question was not fully formulated and therefore not fully answered in my last post. Forgive me, I'm new to using stack overflow.

My professor has assigned a problem set, and we are required to use dplyr and other tidyverse packages. I'm very aware that most (if not all) the tasks that I'm trying to execute are possible in base r, but that's not in agreement with my instructions.

First we are asked to generate a tibble of 1000 random samples from a uniform distribution:

```
2a.  Create a new tibble called uniformDf containing a variable called unifSamples that contains 10000 random samples from a uniform distribution.  You should use the runif() function to create the uniform samples. {r 2a}

uniformDf <- tibble(unifSamples = runif(1000))
```

This goes well.

Then we are asked to loop thru this tibble 1000 times, each time choosing 20 random samples and computing the mean and saving it to a tibble:

```
2c.  Now let's loop through 1000 times, sampling 20 values from a uniform distribution and computing the mean of the sample, saving this mean to a variable called sampMean within a tibble called uniformSampleMeans. {r 2c}

unif_sample_size = 20 # sample size
n_samples = 1000 # number of samples

# set up q data frame to contain the results
uniformSampleMeans <- tibble(sampMean=rep(NA,n_samples))

# loop through all samples.  for each one, take a new random sample, 
# compute the mean, and store it in the data frame

for (i in 1:n_samples){
  uniformSampleMeans$sampMean[i] <- uniformDf %>%
  sample_n(unif_sample_size) %>%
  summarize(sampMean = mean(sampMean))
}
```

This all runs, well, I believe until I look at my `uniformSampleMeans` tibble. Which looks like this:

```
1   0.471271611726843
2   0.471271611726843
3   0.471271611726843
4   0.471271611726843
5   0.471271611726843
6   0.471271611726843
7   0.471271611726843
...
1000    0.471271611726843
```

All the values are identical! Does anyone have any insight as to why my output is like this? I'd be less concerned if they varied by +/- 0.000x values seeing as how this is from a distribution that ranges from 0 to 1 but the values are all identical even out to the 15th decimal place! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You have `sampMean = mean(sampMean)`. You haven't shown where you create the `sampMean` object, but it looks like a fixed value that's produced outside the for loop. It should probably be `sampMean = mean(unifSamples)`.

Comment: YES thank you! I now realize how dumb of a mistake this was.

Answer (score 1):

The following selects random `unif_sample_size` rows and gives it's `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
uniformDf %>% sample_n(unif_sample_size) %>% pull(unifSamples) %>% mean
#[1] 0.5563638
```

If you want to do this `n` times use `replicate` and repeat it `n` times

```
n <- 10
replicate(n, uniformDf %>%
               sample_n(unif_sample_size) %>%
               pull(unifSamples) %>% mean)
#[1] 0.5070833 0.5259541 0.5617969 0.4695862 0.5030998 0.5745950 0.4688153 0.4914363 0.4449804 0.5202964
```